# Python appending to a dictionary list

Tags: python, dictionary, key, key-value

So I have a text file with a list of two numbers then a new line with another two numbers and so on. Example would be:

```
     2000 5000
     2000 5001
     3000 5000 
     4000 7777
      ......
```

I'm trying to create a dictionary that will have a key increment by 1 for every new number in the first index when reading the line and have the value be a list with both the first number and the second number in the text file. so for my example i would like to have

```
{0: ['2000', '5000', '5001'], 1: ['3000', 5000'], 2: ['4000', '7777']}
```

I've already read in the file hence the first 3 lines of the code

My code is as followed

```
    testing = {}
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(lines)):
      x = (lines[i].split(' '))
      if x[0] in testing:
         testing[count].append(x[1])
      else:
         testing[count] =x[0]
         testing[count].append(x[1])

         count += 1
```

The problem im getting is that its only printing out one dictionary key and value.

Comment: There is no built-in 'dictionary list'.  Aside from the missing ', ` {0: '2000', '5000', '5001' 1: '3000', 5000' 2: '4000', '7777'}` is not valid syntax.

Comment: Also, if you are going to have incrementally increasing integer keys, why are you using a dictionary rather than a list?

Comment: well maybe that would be a better approach. Still all new to this. The whole point was i want to have an ID which in my case is the count and that ID would have all the connected components from the set of numbers

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the count outside your for loop. Move your count = 0 to before the loop.

```
count = 0
testing = {}

for i in range(len(lines)):
  x = (lines[i].split(' '))

  if x[0] in testing:
     testing[count].append(x[1]):
  else:
     testing[count] =x[0]
     testing[count].append(x[1]):

     count += 1
```

Comment: ahh yes okay i fixed that. Now im trying to think of a place to increment my count because the way i have it now when it goes to the second line the count is 1 but i need 5001 to be stored in the list with 2000 and 5000